# Is a non-negative function which satisfies the parallelogram identity continuous?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, continuity

My question is motivated by [this Mathoverflow post about inner products](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/123/linearity-of-the-inner-product-using-the-parallelogram-law), where it's written in one of the answers that

> ...In fact, one can derive continuity using only the inequality |u|2≥0 and the parallelogram law.) Also, an algebraic argument must work over any field on characteristic 0.

**My question:** Let $G$ be an abelian group, and $\phi:G \to \mathbb{R}$ a non-negative function. If $\phi$ satisfies the parallelogram identity
$$
2 \phi(x) + 2 \phi(y) = \phi(x+y) + \phi(x-y)
$$
then is it the following also true?
$$
\lim_{\phi(h) \to 0} \phi(x + h) = \phi(x) 
$$

I have not been able to easily find any proofs online, but expected there to be some.

Thanks for any answers or references.

**Edit**: I think I came up with a proof which uses the parallelogram law a couple of times to show
$$\phi(0) = 0$$
$$\phi(-x) = \phi(x)$$
$$\phi(kx) = k^2\phi(x) , \hspace{8mm}k \in \mathbb{N}$$
\begin{align}
\Bigg| \phi(x + h) - \phi(x) \Bigg|
    &= \Bigg| \frac{1}{2 k} \Big\{ \phi(x + kh) - \phi(x - kh) \Big\} + \phi(h) \Bigg| \\
    & \le \Bigg| \frac{1}{2 k} \Big\{ \phi(x + kh) + \phi(x - kh) \Big\} \Bigg| + \phi(h) \\
&= \frac{1}{k} \Big\{ \phi(x) + \phi(kh) \Big\} + \phi(h) \\
&=  \frac{1}{k} \Big\{ \phi(x) + k^2 \phi(h) \Big\}  + \phi(h) \\
&=  \frac{1}{k} \Big\{ \phi(x) \Big\} + (k + 1) \phi(h) \\
\end{align}
when $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Note that the assumption that $V$ is a real vector space is not really relevant--your condition makes sense for any abelian group.  And if you have any counterexample where $V$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, you can get one where it's an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space by just taking a big direct sum of copies of $V$ (and taking the sum of the $\phi$'s on each coordinate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\phi(x)=0$, then the parallelogram law gives $$\phi(x+h)=2\phi(h)-\phi(x-h)\leq 2\phi(h)$$ and so your limit condition holds.  Let us now assume $\phi(x)\neq 0$; we may scale $\phi$ to assume that $\phi(x)=1$.  I now claim that $$\phi(x+h)\geq 1-4\sqrt{\phi(h)}$$ for all $h$ such that $\phi(h)$ is sufficiently small.  The desired limit condition easily follows (we can get an upper bound on $\phi(x+h)=2+2\phi(h)-\phi(x-h)$ using the lower bound on $\phi(x-h)$).

To prove the claim, suppose we have $h$ such that $\phi(x+h)<1-4\sqrt{\phi(h)}$.  Let $C=1-\phi(x+h)$, so $C>4\sqrt{\phi(h)}$.  Note that the parallelogram law can be rearranged to $$\phi(x)-\phi(x+y)=\phi(x-y)-\phi(x)-2\phi(y).$$  We then see by induction that $$\phi(x+kh)-\phi(x+(k+1)h)= C-2k\phi(h)$$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ (the base case $k=0$ being the definition of $C$).  It follows that $$\phi(x+kh)=1-kC+k(k-1)\phi(h)$$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.  The idea now is that because $C$ is large, we can choose $k$ appropriately to make $\phi(x+kh)$ negative and reach a contradiction.  If $\phi(h)=0$, we see immediately that $\phi(x+kh)<0$ for $k$ sufficiently large since $C>0$.  So let us suppose $\phi(h)\neq 0$; to minimize $\phi(x+kh)$ we complete the square in $k$ and write $$\phi(x+kh)=\phi(h)(k-a)^2+1-\phi(h)a^2$$ where $a=\frac{\phi(h)+C}{2\phi(h)}>\frac{C}{2\phi(h)}$.  Since $C>4\sqrt{\phi(h)}$, $\phi(h)a^2>4$.  We can now choose an integer $k$ such that $|k-a|<1$ and find that $$\phi(x+kh)<\phi(h)-3$$ which is negative for $\phi(h)$ sufficiently small.  This contradiction completes the proof.

Comment: Wow, thanks a bunch.